# Can I create a mock that conforms to an interface and is also aware of methods on its base class?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using Moq to test a presenter in a WinForms app. The presenter has a view. The view conforms to `ISomeControl`, and inherits from `UserControl`

In testing this presenter, I want to test that the `Show()` method on the View was called.

So I create a mock like this:

```
var someControl = new Mock<ISomeControl>();
```

But here's the problem: In my application, there's a place where I cast the `ISomeControl` to a `Control` so that I can call the base class Show(). And because the Mock only knows it's an `ISomeControl`, I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy_1' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base **abstract** class that inherits both `ISomeControl` and `UserControl` for the purpose of mocking in the unit test.

```
public abstract class SomeDummyControl : UserControl, ISomeControl { 
    //...
}
```

This should allow for the mock to be aware of both types.

```
var mock = new Mock<SomeDummyControl>();
//...arrange setup

var dummyControl = mock.Object;
//...pass the dummy as a dependency

//just to show that it should be able to cast
var control = dummyControl as Control;
var someControl = dummyControl as ISomeControl;
```

The mock can be verified like this when needed

```
mock.Verify(m => m.Show(), Times.AtLeastOnce()); //verifies that the Show method was called.
```

Read up more on Moq here [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: I thought you could only create Mocks of Interfaces. Not of concrete classes. I also didn't know about the As<>() method. Very useful. I'll try this in the morning (tired now) and will mark as answer when I get it working. Thanks for the help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Trevor, I may have misused the `As<>()` in my original answer. the verify will still work on the mock. The `As<>()` method is very useful but was not applied properly in the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

A mock can be made to implement multiple interfaces

A snippet from the [Moq Quick Start](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) shows how to do this:

```
// implementing multiple interfaces in mock
var foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
var disposableFoo = foo.As<IDisposable>();
// now the IFoo mock also implements IDisposable :)
disposableFoo.Setup(df => df.Dispose());

//implementing multiple interfaces in single mock
var foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
foo.Setup(f => f.Bar()).Returns("Hello World");
foo.As<IDisposable>().Setup(df => df.Dispose());
```